# Android - onTouchListener with count

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I want the button to launch the settings activity after the third click. Right now it is not working at all. How can I do that?

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.Einstellungen)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                int counter = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    counter++;
                    if(counter==3) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                                Button view = (Button) v;
                                view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                                v.invalidate();
                                break;
                            }
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, settings.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                                Button view = (Button) v;
                                view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                                view.invalidate();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently counter is increased with every touch action. For example if you place your finger on the screen (+1) then you drag a bit (+2-5) then you move your finger off the screen (+1 ) now your counter is more than 3 and the if block is not reached.

I would advise you to use a click listener for that:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.Einstellungen)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ++counter;
        if (counter == 3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // Reset the counter (if you want to)
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

That way you can keep the other functionality in `onTouch` and still be able to start the other activity after 3 clicks have been registered.

Note: remember to remove the counter logic from onTouch listener and also remove startActivity from Action_UP event.